# How to add several values to a property of an specific object in a list?

Tags: c#, list, windows-forms-designer

I have a `List` of `Students` and I need to add some grades to an specific `Student` inside that `List`, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that without erasing the previous grade I just added.  Is there any way to do that?

I have a method in a class named `Classroom` that does something like this this:

```
public void AddGrade(string studentID, int grade) {
    Students specificStudent = StudentsList.Find(foundStudent => foundStudent.studentID == studentID);
    if(specificStudent != null) {
        specificStudent.Grade = grade;
    }
}
```

But this only adds one grade and replaces it every time

Comment: you have to show us the definition of the student class so we can see how the grades are stored

Comment: You can acess every public property of everything stored in a collection. But grades should propably be a collection, based on the classes taken by that student...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a list of Grade in Student Object, for  e.g

```
class Student
{
    int studentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Grade> Grades { get; set; } //(or public List<int> Grades { get; set; })
}
```

and then,

```
public void AddGrade(string studentID, int grade)
{
    Student specificStudent = StudentsList.Find(foundStudent => foundStudent.studentID == studentID);
    if (specificStudent != null)
    {
        specificStudent.Grades.Add(grade);
    }
}
```